# How to redisplay blank html form in php after validation on submit fails. Without using header redirect?

Tags: php, forms, oop, refresh

I am new to php, this is my first post, my apologies about the formatting and the sloppiness of my coding. I'm not sure exactly how to post code. but I believe my question is fairly simple.

I am learning php OOP and trying to re-display an html form in PHP that is called from an object function `displayContactForm()` using `method='POST'` that I created from an object class with other various member functions that just simply echo html tags and display a simple `contact.php page with an html form.

All i'm trying to do is re-display the form with blank values after user hits submit and validation fails, so that the form essentially is cleared and user has to re-enter information. I wrote one `if/else` statement to handle the submit which will check if `$_POST` is set, and fields are `!empty`, (else) "redisplay cleared form (or) clear form somehow"? I posted my code for my php page below. The if-else statement is line 31-38. I can't use header relocation. The suggested line for my else statement I was supposed to use for this project was $this->displayContactForm($this->form); to redisplay the form. But it just duplicates the form beneath the original form that is on the page, and I end up with two forms? i'm confused?... Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
require('./PageLib.php');
require('./ContactFormLib.php');

//created a class called ContactPage that extends class Page
class ContactPage extends Page{
    public $form;
    public function __construct($arg=NULL) {
        $this->form = new ContactForm(); 
    }

    //OVERRIDDEN Page::displayPage()
    public function displayPage(){
        echo "<html>\n<head>\n";
        //HEAD/////////////////

        $this->displayTitle();
        $this->displayStyles();
        echo "</head>\n<body>\n";

        //HEADER///////////////

        $this->displayHeader();
        $this->displayNav($this->navLinks);

        //CONTENT//////////////

        $this->displayContactForm($this->form);
        echo $this->content;
        $this->displayFooter();

        if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) &&     !empty($_POST['email'])){
            echo " Checked form values. Now echoing content to page.";
        }
        else {
            $this->displayContactForm($this->form);        
        }      
        echo "\n</body>\n</html>\n";

        public function displayContactForm($f) {
            $f->displayForm(); 
        }

    }
    $contactpage = new ContactPage();
    $contactpage->pageTitle = "Contact Page";
    $contactpage->headerTitle = "Contact - OOP php Page Builder";
    $contactpage->content="<h3>Contact Page Content</h3>\n";
    $contactpage->displayPage();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with just PHP. You will have to use Ajax in combination with PHP to perform this task. PHP by itself requires a page refresh to "re_display" content.